# .NET SQL via Petapoco "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >="

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, petapoco

I see that this error is common but I didn't manage to get a solution for my case, or I didn't manage to understand the exact cause for the problem.

I am executing the follow query from a .NET repository through PetaPoco ORM

```
var foundEntries = Database.Execute("SELECT COUNT(GroupName) 
                                     FROM Group 
                                     WHERE GroupName=@0 AND IsDeleted=0"
                                    , groupName);
```

The result is to get:

*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.*

The weird thing is that when I execute it in SQL Server environment, there is no problem at all.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: The query in your question will not cause that error. There must be another query executed by the framework that's causing it. I suggest you trace the actual statements being sent to SQL Server to identify the problem query.

Comment: Do you have a method Database.ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: @gnsanty there is not such a method unfortunately

Comment: What about `ExecuteScalar ()` ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thank you but no luck with that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`SingleOrDefault`** instead of `Execute`

```
var foundEntries = Database.SingleOrDefault<int>("SELECT COUNT(GroupName) 
                                     FROM Group 
                                     WHERE GroupName=@0 AND IsDeleted=0"
                                    , groupName);
```